# Are Firefox Keyboard Shortcuts only activated at browser start-up?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

In a Firefox restartless addon, the keyboard shortcuts disappear after disabling and enabling the addon. Console does not log any error (`try{}catch{}`).

On checking the `Browser Toolbox` the `key` is inserted back in the `<keyset id="mainKeyset">` but the shortcut is not working and the modifiers do not appear on the contextmenu.

So the question is, have I missed something or Keyboard Shortcuts are only activated at browser start-up?

Comment: Since you solved this yourself (great!), the proper way is to answer your own question and accept your own answer, instead of editing your question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem ...

While the order of (creating/insertion) of `keyset` & `context menuitem` did not matter on browser start-up, it did matter on re-enabling the restartless addon. Moving the `keyset` creating/insertion to before `menuitem` creation/insertion, solved the problem.

Per request:
At first I had the `/* ContextMenu Menuitem */` section first and then the `/* keyset */` section. 
By putting the /* keyset */`section first, the`keyset`was created & inserted before inserting the`contextmenu menutiem` and that fixed the problem.

```
let contextMenu = window.document.getElementById('contentAreaContextMenu');

/* keyset */
let mainKeyset = window.document.getElementById('mainKeyset'); // parent -> #main-window
let keyset = window.document.createElement('keyset');
//keyset.setAttribute('id', this.id + '-keyset'); // if you need to have an id
let key = window.document.createElement('key');
key.setAttribute('id', this.id + '-key');
key.setAttribute('modifiers', 'accel shift');
key.setAttribute('keycode', 'VK_F2');
key.setAttribute('oncommand', 'void(0);');
key.addEventListener('command', this, false);
keyset.appendChild(key); // add the key to keyset
mainKeyset.parentNode.appendChild(keyset);  // add the keyset to the window.document

/* ContextMenu Menuitem */
let docfrag = window.document.createDocumentFragment(); // temporary container
let menuseparator = window.document.createElement('menuseparator');
let menuitem = window.document.createElement('menuitem');
//menuitem.setAttribute('id', this.id + '-menuitem'); // if you need to have an id
menuitem.setAttribute('class', 'menuitem-iconic');
menuitem.setAttribute('label', this.menuitemLabel);
//menuitem.setAttribute('hidden', 'true'); // starts from hidden
menuitem.setAttribute('accesskey', 'R');
menuitem.setAttribute('key', this.id + '-key');
//menuitem.style.listStyleImage = 'url(chrome://' + this.id  + '/skin/icon16.png)'; // this also works
menuitem.setAttribute('style', 'list-style-image: url(chrome://' + this.id  + '/skin/icon16.png);');
menuitem.addEventListener('command', this, false);

docfrag.appendChild(menuseparator); // adding the menuseparator to temporary container
docfrag.appendChild(menuitem); // add the menuitem to temporary container
contextMenu.appendChild(docfrag); // add the temporary container to the contextMenu
```

Comment: Thx for sharing man. Can you post the code that you were doing before and then after the fix? That will help out a lot.

Comment: @Noitidart ... I put the final code for you. The before code was exactly the same but the `/* keyset */` section was after `/* ContextMenu Menuitem */`